# Make bottom margin smaller while using div=calc

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

Problem: the bottom margin is too large, i.e. I want the text to run further towards the footer, i.e. closer to the footer rule in the example below, but still keep `div=calc` such that the rest fits as it does now. Minimum Working Example showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[DIV=calc, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage} 

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance :)!

Edit: Screenshot showing the problem added. I'd like to shrink the vertical space that I indicated with the arrow.
[image]

Comment: I think the result of your mwe looks quite nicely. However, how much space would you like between the bottom of the text and the footer?

Comment: @alexraasch I am not sure how much exactly, maybe about half of what it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add `footheight=0mm` to the options of `\documentclass{scrartcl}`:

[image: footline]

Comment: However, I think you should re-read the KOMA script's documentation once again carefully. Chapter 2 explains everything you need to know about headlines and footlines in detail and usually no other packages are necessary.